# Do Rumbles Auto-Attacks when OverHeated affect structures?

Tags: league-of-legends

I like to play Rumble and one thing I do out of instinct is overheating at the turret (after killing the other toplaner) and auto-attack it while overheated for the bonus AD.

It makes me slightly vulnerable there under turret.

But do Rumbles overheated auto-attacks really **affect structures**(I can't really tell from looking at the screen)? Or do they only work on minions/champions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, Rumbles abilities don't affect the damage dealt to structures.

They damage dealt to turrets is calculated is a special way:

> Damage to a turret is based on your base attack damage plus the higher of your bonus attack damage or 40% of your ability power. It is not affected by any kind of armor or magic penetration

**There are some [abilities that deal bonus damage to turrets](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret#Abilities_that_deal_bonus_damage_to_turrets), Rumble is not in that list.**

read [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/190767/61976) for additional information why you should not overheat when attacking a turret.

Answer (score 1):

No, the turrets will not be affected.

Also a thing to note: **You don't gain bonus AD**. Overheating is an on-hit effect that scales off with 25% of your AP and your level while dealing magic damage (not physical). You should only use the overheating if you can win a melee trade against another champion or if you want more damage on your auto attacks if jungling or farming. Using it while pushing a turret is more or less counterproductive since it silences you and resets your heat meter which basically puts you in a bad spot if you're getting ganked.

Rumble was released in a time where damaging a turret with spells or on-hit effects was an extremely rare ability and they didn't rework his passive since.